# Template base class can store pointers to derived but not objects - why?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code and I'm wondering why if I change the

T* e;

line to

T e;

it throws an error: "Base1::e' uses undefined class 'Derived'"

```
template<class T> class Base1
{
public:
  Base1() {};
  virtual ~Base1() {};

  T* e;
};

class Base2
{
  public:
  Base2() {};
};

class Derived : public Base1<Derived>, Base2
{
  public:
  Derived() {};
  ~Derived() {};
};
```

Comment: I thnk it would create infinitive number of objects, if you think every e inside Base1 has another e...

Comment: This makes no sense. You're trying to put a box inside itself. It's no different from `struct X { X x; };`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one thing, at the point where you specify that `Derived` inherits from `Base1<Derived>` your `Derived` class is not yet completely defined (aka. incomplete type) so the compiler can't instantiate it inside `Base1`. This is the reason why you're getting this specific error message.

But even if the compiler could instantiate a `Derived` at that point, what would happen? `Base1<Derived>` would contain a `Derived` which inherits from `Base1<Derived>` which contains a `Derived` which inherits... *ad infinitum*. Obviously this isn't valid.

Comment: And if it isn't obvious why it's invalid, try to compute `sizeof(Derived)` by hand!

Comment: got it, just a small clarification: why is the T* pointer allowed instead?

Comment: @DavidKernin: because the size of a pointer (whatever it points to) is always known. So even though `Derived` is still an incomplete type at this point, `Derived*` is fully defined and can be instantiated.